# UIKIT_EXTERN method, how to override for unit testing?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, uikit

I am writing unit tests for my view classes. i found a method name    UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning().

```
     if(UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()){
<steps>
    }
```

Usually i wrote protocols to make the methods to do what i want to but when i override this method like this

```
UIKIT_EXTERN BOOL UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning(){
return YES;
```

}

This one is not getting called, can you please help me to understand why it works so ? I believe there could be only one implementation per a extern method, please clarify.

Comment: A function can't be overridden.

Comment: I was so dumb that i did not understand that until you mentioned. Yes it is a C functions so no overloading. Thanks